# How to show 'tags' in 'Wordpress Pages' [not Posts]

Tags: pages, template-tags

I have found a way to have the ‘category’ the page is recorded against to display at the top of the ‘page’ (this is not a post but a WordPress ‘page’).

I would also like to display the ‘tags’ that have been recorded against this page but haven’t been able to find a way to achieve this – all the search results talk about are ‘removing tags from posts’ or getting ‘pages of tags’. These results make my ability to select the correct Google search to get my answer frustrating!

To get the category of the page to show I added the following to my ‘functions.php’ in my child theme directory:

`add_filter('twentytwenty_show_categories_in_entry_header', '__return_true');`

Is there an equivalent piece of code I can use to display the tags assigned to this page also?

Many thanks for all help provided,

Richard

Answer (score 1):

enter your tags instead of the specified ones or delete the extra ones:

```
function wps_display_custom_tags ($post_meta) {
  // delete meta tags you do not want to display
  return array( 'author', 'post-date', 'comments', 'sticky', 'tags');
}
add_filter('twentytwenty_post_meta_location_single_top', 'wps_display_custom_tags');
```

Comment: Many thanks @ktscript, do I add this into 'functions.php' in my child theme or somewhere else?